Why use white noise over an impulse signal (or vice versa) to understand how a system would behave?
An impulse signal and white noise both have a flat spectrum. When they are passed into a system, the response will indicate how each frequency component will be modified by the system. Is there any advantage to using one over the other when it comes to finding the response of a system?

https://audioroundtable.com/misc/Mueller.pdf : An exhaustive treatise on measuring transfer functions and impulse responses, arguing why sweeps are the preferable choice for the majority of measurement tasks

That's an interesting paper.

An impulse excitation is certainly simple: you get the directly the impulse response. However impulse performs very poorly in the presence of noise since they tend to have very low energy.
With the same amplitude constraints, white noise has typically a lot more overall energy and results in much better Signal to Noise ratio of the measurements. It's a bit more tricky to unwind the measurement signal especially  if you also need the phase of the transfer function, but that can certainly be done.
Both are "white" which is unsuitable for certain measurement task. In most audio applications, the noise is either pink or brown and in order to get decent signal to noise at all frequency you want an excitation spectrum that's similar to the noise spectrum.
My personal favorite are periodic low crest pseudo random sequences that are tailored to the noise properties and the specific application requirements.

It depends on measurement noise and your ability to produce a pure impulse. First radars used 100s of kW impulses and yet, were limited in range to few tens of miles. In 1947, Darlington proposed to use chirp which has "perfect" autocorrelation property, i.e. if you convolve it with itself, you get a delta function. Thus, you do not need so powerful transmitter, you can trade-in the power with duration. The resulting SNR will be the same (in the 1st approx) as far as the impulse's energy equals to the total energy of chirp.
The same can be worked out with any "perfect" or "near-perfect" functions as MLS. Using white noise requires much more computational effort (see Lennart Ljung's book "System Identification: theory for the user". If your measurement noise is not white, you need to color your excitation accordingly.
Some methods are better than others in dealing with weak non-linearities, discontinuities, etc - but that's another topic. In audio, chirp aka sine sweep is a traditional choice - not because it is so good but because it's easy to perform and [mis]interpret.

Welcome to the DSP.SE .  Back in the previous century, I did a little MLS tutorial explaining the math.  MLS is not so good for non-linearities.  Nonlinearities in the system cause apparent spurious spikes in the measure impulse response.

The generation of a really, truly, honest-to-goodness impulse not feasible practically, and even if it were, the power supply company would have a hissy fit if you tried to do so. Furthermore, keep in mind that most so-called linear systems are linear actually linear only to some limited extent. Yes, the model of a resistor $R$ says that the DC current $I$ flowing through the resistor when a DC voltage of $V$ is applied to the resistor is given by $I = \frac VR$, but most engineers know that applying a gazillion  volts to a 1-ohm resistor will not result in a gazillion-ampere DC current flowing through it for all eternity, just for a fraction of a picosecond till the resistor evaporates in a flash of smoke! Circuits such as audio amplifiers operate in a linear mode only for small signals: the overall V-I curve is nonlinear and can be approximated by a straight line only over a small range of values surrounding the operating point etc.
In short, applying an impulse or a just a large input pulse to a so-called linear system is not very useful. It is much better to use a (low-level) PN sequence of fairly long period as the input to the system (as Hilmar has suggested), and cross-correlate the input and output to identify the impulse response of the system; the results are much better than when you whack the system with an alleged impulse and drive it into the nonlinear region.
See this answer of mine for more details.

This is a sleazy trick:
So you can start with a driver signal having a spectrum magnitude of whatever you want.  Start with an kronecker impulse.  Or a few randomly spaced kronecker impulses.  Or a linear-frequency sweep.  Or an exponential-frequency sweep.  Or windowed PRNG noise.  Or windowed anything.
Just try not to let the frequency content at any frequency be zero.
This can be a long signal, like $2^{18}$ or $2^{20}$ samples.  Modern FFTs are fine with that and shouldn't have any numerical issues.  Use double.
So then FFT this long signal that's tapered at the ends.  Use fftshift() in MATLAB and swap the two halves going in so that the middle of the window is at $n=0$.
Then with that spectrum, scramble up the phase with a low-pass filtered PRNG noise.  Like throw the old phase away and replace it with this low-pass filtered PRNG noise.  Start at zero frequency ($k=0$) and add this slowly-changing random noise to the phase up to Nyquist ($k=\frac{N}2$).  Reflect this phase and negate it for the higher bins (which really represent negative frequencies).
Then inverse FFT.
What you'll get out has the same frequency content in magnitude, but it's gonna sound out of this world.  Wild-ass signal coming out.
Potentially a decently low crest factor driving function having whatever frequency content, in magnitude, that you want.
